# Storing and Retrieving Dynamic 2-D Array in Session or ViewBag MVC C#

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array

I have this chunk of code in my controller that makes two separate lists of ID's and Name's but I will turn that into a dynamic 2-D array eventually once I understand a few things:

```
var UserEntitiesID = db.tblUserEntities.Where(x => x.UserID == userid).ToList(); //userid comes from aad
var IDList = new List<int?>();
var NameList = new List<string>();
foreach (var entitiesitem in UserEntitiesID)
{
    foreach (var item in db.tblEntitiesGroups.Where(x => x.EntitiesID == entitiesitem.EntitiesID))
    {
        IDList.Add(item.EntitiesGroupID);
        NameList.Add(db.tblGroups.Where(x => x.GroupID == item.GroupID).First().GroupName);
    }                       
}
Session["IDList"] = IDList;
Session["NameList"] = NameList;
```

**My question is this:** How do I insert this possible dynamic 2-D array into a Session variable or Viewbag item, then pass that off to a view and then read the first and second value for the first record, separately? I do not know how to correctly dynamically index the array on the view to read each value out separately.

Currently I have this code in my view to display the ID's and Name's separately:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["IDList"] as string))
{
    foreach (var IDs in (IEnumerable<int?>)Session["IDList"])
    {
        <h5>@IDs.ToString()</h5>
    }
    foreach (var names in (IEnumerable<string>)Session["NameList"])
    {
        <h5>@names.ToString()</h5>
    }
 }
```

Basically I want this layout in the array: 
0{"ID", "Name"}
1{"ID", "Name"}
And so on...

Thanks!

Comment: If you just made a `class UserViewModel { string Name {get;set;} int UserId {get;set;} }` then you could pass a `List<UserViewModel>` and `foreach( var user in Model.Users) { ... @user.Name  ... @user.UserId }`

Comment: @AaronLS That actually makes perfect sense. I'll give that try, thank you!

Comment: @Alex I'm looking to do the same thing. Please provide the outcome of your efforts. If it worked perhaps AaronLS could make his response into an answer which could be marked as such. That would make this question valuable to the community. Thanks!

Comment: @LReeder14 I actually did use AaronLS code in a different part of the project where I created a view model of specific values. So if AaronLS can change his comment to an answer I will mark it as such, it worked great! Thanks!